# What is a more efficient query for this many to many eloquent query?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

There are the following tables: `lists`, `items`, and the pivot table `items_to_lists`, which has the columns `list_id` and `items_id`.

I know the `list_id` and `account_id` and I need to get all the `items` (with specific columns) that belong to it and belong to the `account` (there is `accounts` table),

I currently tried the following:

```
$items = Lists::with(['items' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('column1', 'column2');
    }])->find(3);
```

But it looks like it's not efficient because it also fetches the pivot table data with every item:

```
"items": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Item Name",
    "pivot": {
        "id"..
        "list_id"..
        "item_id"..
    }
},
// ..
```

What query is better for this purpose? Is it more close to a raw SQL, or I can still make this eloquent efficient and choose only the needed data (without the pivot)?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Also show us your current SQL query attempt. (And add a tag for the dbms you're using.)

Comment: It will alwayhs fetch the pivot table, because it can't proccess the relationship without fetching the pivot table. So don't worry about that.

Comment: @jarlh I couldn't figure a raw SQL that matches what Laravel did in this case with the many to many relationship (I am not fluent in SQL to say the least). I was just wondering if someone that knows that might give me a hint if something better can be done. (Were joins used behind the scenes here?). Bulent - How can I filter only my wanted columns then? Because I need to pass collection of specific columns but the pivot is always returned, even if I do the above query to only select specific columns

Comment: Set `protected $hidden = ['pivot'];`

Comment: @Tpojka but is there a way to do it on the fly? And if I do use `$hidden` and I will need the pivot data, what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent must have the pivot data. If you remove the `topic_id` from the selected columns, no results will be returned because of the way it associates the data.

Assuming you have a pivot model for `items_to_lists`, you could create a `HasMany` relationship between List and `ItemToList` (or however you want to call that model) and then customize the query so it joins to your `Item` model.

```php
class ItemToList extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'items_to_lists';
}
```

```php
class List extends Model
{
    ...
    public function item_to_list()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemToList::class, 'item_id');
    }
}
```

```php
$items = Lists::query()
    ->with(['item_to_list' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('i.name', 'list_id', 'item_id')
              ->join('items as i', 'i.id', 'item_id');
    }])
    ->find(3);
```

For comparison, your original query creates the following SQL queries:

```sql
-- Query 1
select ...
from "lists" where "lists"."id" = 3
limit 1

-- Query 2
select
    "items"."name",
    "items_to_lists"."list_id" as "pivot_list_id",
    "items_to_lists"."item_id" as "pivot_item_id"
from "items"
inner join "items_to_lists" on "items"."id" = "items_to_lists"."item_id"
where "items_to_lists"."topic_id" in (3)"
```

And the alternative I wrote generates the following queries

```sql
-- Query 1
select ...
from "lists" where "lists"."id" = 3
limit 1

-- Query 2
select
    "i"."name",
    "list_id",
    "item_id"
from "items_to_lists"
inner join "items" as "i" on "item_id" = "i"."id"
where "items_to_lists"."list_id" in (3)
```

As you can see, the queries are pretty much the same.

Comment: that is a really detailed answer, thank you